# Problem 1.45 (Boolean-valued ordinals) (J.Bell, boolean-valued models and indipendence proof, 3rd edition)

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Problem 1.45 (Boolean-valued ordinals) (J.Bell, boolean-valued models and indipendence proof, 3rd edition)

(i) Show that, for any formula φ(x), $ [[ ∃α .φ(α)]] = \bigvee_α [[φ( \hat{α})]]$ and $[[∀α.φ(α)]] = \bigwedge_α [[φ(\hat{α})]]$. Thus, quantifications over ordinals in $V^{(B)}$ can be replaced by
suprema and infima in B over standard ordinals.

(ii) Show that the following conditions on $u ∈ V^{(B)}$ are equivalent:

(a) [[Ord(u)]] = 1;

(b) there is a set A of ordinals and a partition of unity {$a_ξ$: ξ ∈ A} in B
such that $[[ u = \Sigma _{ξ∈A} a_ξ · \hat{ξ} ]]= 1 $.

someone can help me?

Comment: I think that this was asked before on the site.

Comment: At least something related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97163/boolean-valued-models-have-no-essentially-new-ordinals