# How to find a condition that "decides" the value of a name for an ordinal

Tags: set-theory, forcing

In a paper I'm reading involving forcing, the following is used without proof, and it seems to be stated as if it is "obvious," but I don't see why.  It's probably either easy or known, but I might not read the appropriate reference. Can anyone help?

**Let $\overline{\alpha}$ be a $P$-name for an ordinal. Then for any $p\in P$ there is a $q\leq p$ and an $\alpha$ in the ground model such that $q\Vdash \overline{\alpha} = \check\alpha$.**

(Here $\check\alpha$ is the canonical name).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given any $p \in P$, let $G$ be a generic filter for $P$ containing $p$.  Since forcing adds no new ordinals, and as $\overline{\alpha}$ is a $P$-name for an ordinal, there is an ordinal $\alpha$ in the ground model such that $\overline{\alpha}[G] = \alpha = \check{\alpha}[G]$.  By the Forcing Theorem there is a $q \in G$ such that $q \Vdash \overline{\alpha} = \check{\alpha}$, and by extending if necessary we may assume $q \leq p$.

The above both gives the result you are looking for, and, equivalently, proves that the set
$$\{ q \in P : ( \exists \alpha ) ( q \Vdash \overline{\alpha} = \check{\alpha} \}$$ is dense in $P$

Comment: The fact that the set in your first sentence is dense is precisely what I don't see.  I believe that V[G] has no new ordinals, but the "essentially because" is I guess where I'm getting stuck.  Your parenthetical sentence seems to suggest that you're using the forcing theorem: if ã = a is true in V[G] then this fact must be forced.

Comment: By the way, I would upvote your answer if I had enough "reputation" to do so.

Comment: Actually, the two parts work on each other, and perhaps I should rearrange the answer.  Knowing that forcing adds no new ordinals allows you to use the Forcing Theorem to conclude that every $p \in P$ has an extension which decides the $P$-name $\bar{\alpha}$, which then means that the set I defined is dense in the partial order.

Comment: That's exactly what my interpretation was.  Thanks, this helped.

Comment: @Albert: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

This is true because forcing extensions do not add ordinals to the universe. So if we know that $\bar\alpha$ is a name which will be interpreted as an ordinal, it would have be interpreted as some ordinal from the ground model.

Which one may depend on the generic filter, but this really just means that at *some* point there will be a condition that will decide the value of that ordinal.

To see why forcing does not add ordinals, here is a Boolean-valued model approach [Boolean-valued models have no essentially new ordinals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97163/boolean-valued-models-have-no-essentially-new-ordinals).

Comment: Isn't the statement the OP wants proof of just a way to state formally _that_ forcing extensions don't add new ordinals?

Comment: @Henning: I thought so at first, but upon further reflection I felt that there is a delicate difference between the two questions. I gave a link to such proof, anyway.